# PHP MySQL Can´t make if inside while loop works retunrs always same id

Tags: php, mysql, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have this code, in which i have a if statement inside while loop, the problem is that i can't make it work because it always returns the same comment ID after the if statement is accomplished. I couldn´t found a solution. I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
while($fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
    $archivos  =  $fila['archivos'];
    $fecha  =  $fila['fecha'];
    $comentarioID  =  $fila['id'];
    $comentario = $fila['comentario'];
    if(strlen($comentario) > 100){
        $comentario = substr($comentario, 0, 100); 
        $vermas = '...<a href="" class="vermas" id="vermas_'.$comentarioID.'">Ver mas</a>';
    }
    echo $comentario.$vermas;
}
```

Comment: It always return the same ID for all the MySQL results after the if statement is accomplished :(

Comment: `$vermas` is not defined if the length is less than or equal to 100?

Comment: show your query code

Comment: `...id="vermas_'.$comentario.'"...` may be?

Comment: Dont use mysql , use mysqli

Comment: @VerdeMc Can you show your query please, and what's the records in your database?

Comment: @J.Pichardo this is my MySQL query: $query = 'SELECT * FROM publicaciones ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15';

$resultado = mysql_query($query);

Comment: The data are comments.

Comment: I need to get the id of each one and the comment itself, but when the if statement is accomplished all the coments after that specific one appears with the same id. the id of the one that accomplish the if statement

Comment: `$comentario`  is the same or `$vermas`? You aren't outputting `$comentarioID` so you don't know if that is or isn't the same.

Comment: sorry i mess it up accidentally, yes we can suppose that $comentario is the same as $comentarioID

Comment: echo $comentarioID.$vermas;

Comment: So the code in the question doesnt match your real code?

Answer (score 1):

First off MySQL is deprecated. Use MySQLi. You should also define **$vermas** outside of the if() statement, because *if* the *strlen* is less than or equal to 100 characters, then **$vermas** will be left undefined.

Try this...

```
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {

    $archivos = $fila['archivos'];  
    $fecha = $fila['fecha'];
    $comentarioID = $fila['id'];
    $comentario = $fila['comentario'];

    if(strlen($comentario) > 100){
        $comentario = substr($comentario, 0, 100); 
    }

    $vermas = "...<a href='' class='vermas' id='vermas_".$comentarioID."'>Ver mas</a>";

    echo $comentario.$vermas;
}
```